# How to Enable mod_php On Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, php

It seems that I cannot enable the mod_php on apache2 using the latest Ubuntu Server.

when I run: `sudo a2enmod php5`

I get this error: `ERROR: Module php5 does not exist!`

however I am convinced I have php installed correctly. I have even gone as far as uninstalling Apache and reinstalling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Further research on my own question I was able to enable php by running:

`sudo a2enmod php7.1`

And then restarting Apache using:

`sudo service apache2 restart`

It looks like I was just trying to enable the incorrect mod.